# SSRS currency not showing as CAD

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, cultureinfo, currency-formatting

Need to show the SSRS currency as CAD 200,000.00 but not able to achieve the same.

Changed the text box properties to Custom and Format as "C".
If the language is passed "en-US" or "en-CA" the format remains the same i.e. $200,000.00. Please Help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to fix if you did a bit of research.  I have an option that should work for you.  First, you can set the textbox value as an expression and simply add the `CAD` to the front of the value.  Then, you'll need to format the field as a decimal using the `FORMAT` function.

```
="CAD " & FORMAT(Fields!myField.Value, "###,###.##")
```

This expression should fill your needs.

Edit based on comment: After a very quick Google search, I found that you cannot avoid some form of hard coding if you intend to pass the currency format based on a report language.  You'll need to include the following expression:

```
=FORMAT(Fields!myField.Value, "c")
```

This will format the field as a currency.  In order to have the language passed from the report language, you need to turn on advanced mode. Below, step 1 shows where to turn on advanced mode.  Step 2 shows where to change the language of the report.  This is the report properties which are accessed when clicking anywhere outside of the report in the report window.

[image]

Here I tried it with `CA-fr`.

[image: image2]

Comment: The solution you provided will be hard coded. This should be language culture based as I may pass "en-US" or "en-CA" or "fr-CA"

Comment: @ShivanBhatia Updated my answer to fit your needs.